# Python Related Question - User Input Date /N00B/

Tags: python

here is my little Python project:

```
from datetime import date

a_date = date(2020,5,1) 
b_date = date.today()
delta = b_date - a_date

print("Start date:", a_date)
print("Today is day:", delta.days +1)

if int(delta.days) <= 30:
  print("Phase: Vegetation")
if int(delta.days) >= 30:
  print("Phase: Flowering")
```

My Questions is: How can I make the user to input "a_date"?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use input() and datetime.date.fromisoformat()

For Python 3.7 and later:

```
from datetime import date

a_date = date.fromisoformat(input("Enter a date (YYYY-MM-DD): "))
b_date = date.today()
delta = b_date - a_date

print("Start date:", a_date)
print("Today is day:", delta.days +1)

if int(delta.days) <= 30:
  print("Phase: Vegetation")
if int(delta.days) >= 30:
  print("Phase: Flowering")
```

For Python version 3.6 and earlier:

```
from datetime import date

def parse_date(date_input):
    return date(int(a_date_input[:4]), int(a_date_input[5:7]), int(a_date_input[8:]))
    
a_date_input = input("Enter a date (YYYY-MM-DD): ")
a_date = parse_date(a_date_input)
b_date = date.today()
delta = b_date - a_date

print("Start date:", a_date)
print("Today is day:", delta.days +1)

if int(delta.days) <= 30:
  print("Phase: Vegetation")
if int(delta.days) >= 30:
  print("Phase: Flowering")
```

Comment: a_date = date.fromisoformat(input("Enter a date (YYYY-MM-DD): "))
AttributeError: type object 'datetime.date' has no attribute 'fromisoformat'

Comment: Are you using Python 3.7+?

Comment: @SvetGEoff Python version 3.7 or later is required to run this. You can check your version in the terminal or command prompt by running `python --version` or `python3 --version`

Comment: At first, I was using 3.6! Both code work perfectly! Is a database like MySQL only solution for me to save this input?

Comment: @SvetGEoff Good to hear! It depends on the size of your project. If you plan on making this into a professional project then MySQL would be a great way to go. However, If you are just making a small hobby project it would be a lot easier to just use .txt files to save your data. Here is a link to Python's Official Documentation about Writing Files: <https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files>

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by using a python built it function `input()`. Between the brackets, I have entered the text that will be printed to a user.

```
from datetime import date

a_date = input('Enter a date')
b_date = date.today()
delta = b_date - a_date

print("Start date:", a_date)
print("Today is day:", delta.days +1)

if int(delta.days) <= 30:
  print("Phase: Vegetation")
if int(delta.days) >= 30:
  print("Phase: Flowering")
```

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/sessions/ffdaadd8bc59ba28/main.py", line 5, in <module>
    delta = b_date - a_date
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'datetime.date' and 'str'

Comment: That's because you asked the user for a STRING input and want to have a DateTime.date format. You have to use date.fromisoformat() function